# nginx basic auth on a file doesn't work

Tags: nginx

```
location = /admin {
        rewrite ^(.*) /admin.php?$1;
        auth_basic "Administrator login";
        auth_basic_user_file /srv/www/test.domain.io/wvb_landing/.htpasswd;
}
```

It doesn't work. Still opens the file admin.php without requesting a password. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What did you do to solve your problem?

Comment: Besides: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467900/nginx-password-protect-not-working).

Comment: if i remove rewrite rule - it does work. My question is - how to make it work with a rewrite rule?

Comment: causes 500 internal server error;